# What is the order of pole of $\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}e^z+\sin(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Find and classify the singularity of $f(z)=\frac{1}{\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}e^z+\sin(z))}$. If it's a pole, find it's order.

As $z\to0$, the denominator will go to $0$, so it's a pole. But I'm having trouble finding the order of this pole. We can write $\frac{\pi}{2}e^z$ and $\sin(z)$ as Laurent series around $0$ (which is just their Taylor series), and then sum them up. But how do I "cosine" the series after that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** You don't need a full series expansion of the denominator at 0. Just looking at its higher derivatives until you find one that is nonzero will suffice -- and you can use the good old symbolic differentiation rules from real calculus to find those.

---

By the way, speaking of "*the* singularity of $f$" is misleading. It has many singularities, one of them at $0$.